# Merging two dataframe using ID and asof

Tags: python, merge, group-by, pandas, time-series

I have two data frame that I wish to join together where the left dataframe have information index by (date, ID) and the right dataframe has information index by (period, ID), where period is year-month.

I end up doing a group by ID for the left frame, iterating thru the groups, select the same group on the right frame, and then doing and asof operation for the index of the group from the left dataframe, like so:

```
def merge_func(base_df, si_df):  
    df_list = list()
    by_cusip = base_df.groupby('cusip8')

    for cusip, group in by_cusip:
        si_df_by_cusip = si_df[si_df.cusip==cusip]
        if len( si_df_by_cusip[ pd.notnull(si_df_by_cusip['sif'])]) > 0:
            group['sif'] = si_df_by_cusip['sif'].asof(group.index)
        else:
            group['sif'] = np.nan
        if len( si_df_by_cusip[ pd.notnull(si_df_by_cusip['si_cover'])]) > 0:
            group['sir'] = si_df_by_cusip['si_cover'].asof(group.index)
        else:
            group['sir'] = np.nan
        df_list.append(group)
    return pd.concat(df_list)
```

But this function is quite slow. Does anyone have a way to make this merge function faster and more efficient?

You may find these links relevant to what I'm trying to accomplish: [sample for doing asof-join](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12322289/kdb-like-asof-join-for-timeseries-data-in-pandas/12336039#12336039) , [merging tables with millions of rows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14614512/merging-two-tables-with-millions-of-rows-in-python/14617925#14617925)

Thank you in advance for your comments and help!

Comment: Can you post some test data?

Comment: the problem becomes slow with millions of rows of data. You can generate two data frames with left having cusip8 (a form of ID) and date and right data frame having cusip (same IDs) and Period ( year-month) and two data fields value1, value2. above my data fields are sif and si_cover

Comment: w/o data this is quite difficult to diagnose. but you can try preprocessing ``si_df`` to groupby ``cusip``, then using ``si_df.get_group(cusip)`` to avoid the continual selection hit

Comment: That was a fantastic suggestion Jeff! That gave me a 5 times speed up!! will try to post some test data soon. Really appreciate it!!

Answer (score 2):

You can just use [the "asof join" feature added to pandas 0.19](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.19.0/whatsnew.html#whatsnew-0190-enhancements-asof-merge):

```
pd.merge_asof(df1, df2, left_on='date', right_on='period', by='ID')
```