# Pandas: add column with the most recent values

Tags: python, datetime, pandas

I have two pandas dataframes, both index with datetime entries. The `df1` has non-unique time indices, whereas `df2` has unique ones. I would like to add a column `df2.a` to `df1` in the following way: for every row in `df1` with timestamp `ts`, `df1.a` should contain the most recent value of `df2.a` whose timestamp is less then `ts`.

For example, let's say that `df2` is sampled every minute, and there are rows with timestamps `08:00:15`, `08:00:47`, `08:02:35` in `df1`. In this case I would like the value from `df2.a[08:00:00]` to be used for the first two rows, and `df2.a[08:02:00]` for the third. How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

apply to rows of df1, reindex on df2 with ffill.

```
df1['df2.a'] = df1.apply(lambda x: pd.Series(df2.a.reindex([x.name]).ffill().values), axis=1)
```

Answer (score 2):

You are describing an [asof-join](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12322289/kdb-like-asof-join-for-timeseries-data-in-pandas), which was just [released in pandas 0.19](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.19.0/whatsnew.html#whatsnew-0190-enhancements-asof-merge).

```
pd.merge(df1, df2, left_on='ts', right_on='a')
```